# C# Class that has a name and a Collection of any object type

Tags: c#, wpf, generics, observablecollection

I am trying to create a list of menus which the user can select from a TreeView. Upon selecting a menu from the tree, I want to show the items within that menu in a separate portion of the window. My first thought on a way to do this is to create a class like below:

```
public class SettingsMenu
{
    public string Name { set; get; }
    public ObservableCollection<object> Items { set; get; }

    public SettingsMenu()
    {
        Name = "";
        Items = new ObservableCollection<object>();
    }

    public SettingsMenu(string _name, ObservableCollection<object> _items)
    {
        Name = _name;
        Items = _items;
    }

    public void AddItem(object _item)
    {
        Items.Add(_item);
    }
}
```

Where "Items" is the items in the menu. I would then create a new instance of this class for each menu in my system, and initialize it with a name and an ObservableCollection of items.

However, the items can be of several custom types. For a basic demonstration of my issue, it would be the equivalent of:

```
    MenuInts = new SettingsMenu("Menu1", new ObservableCollection<int>());
    MenuStrings = new SettingsMenu("Menu2", new ObservableCollection<string>());
    MenuBools = new SettingsMenu("Menu3", new ObservableCollection<bool>());
```

But I get a compiler error:

```
Cannot convert from
'System.Collections.ObjectModel.ObservableCollection<type>' to
'System.Collections.ObjectModel.ObservableCollection<object>'
```

I would like to use one "Menu" class so that I can use it in a consistent way for display and interaction in the UI. Is there a way to have one master class that can contain an ObservableCollection of any type?

Comment: A collection of `int` *is not a collection of `object`*. You can't add an arbitrary object to it, only an `int`. So the type system won't let you shoot yourself in the foot that way. Use `ObservableCollection<Object>` for all of them -- or make `SettingsMenu` generic as well. You may need to write a non-generic base (or an explicitly-implemented non-generic interface) and a generic subclass.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As noted already in Ed Plunkett's comment, you can abstract the functionality you need to a common interface or base class :

```
public interface ISettingsMenu
{
    string Name { set; get; }

    IEnumerable<object> Items { get; }

   void AddItem(object item);
}


public class SettingsMenu<T> : ISettingsMenu
{
    public string Name { set; get; }

    public ObservableCollection<T> Items { set; get; }

    IEnumerable<object>  ISettingsMenu.Items
    {
        get { return Items.Cast<object>(); }
    }

    public void AddItem(object item)
    {
        throw new System.NotImplementedException();
    }

    public SettingsMenu()
    {
        Name = "";
        Items = new ObservableCollection<T>();
    }

    public SettingsMenu(string _name, ObservableCollection<T> _items)
    {
        Name = _name;
        Items = _items;
    }

    public void AddItem(T _item)
    {
        Items.Add(_item);
    }
}
```

In this example Items is exposed as an IEnumerable - If you need to access the ObservableCollection<T> to bind to its events, you might need to an init method to the interface that accepts the control to bind as a parameter.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I do believe it will get me on my way to what I need. I have never worked with interfaces before (although I have used abstract classes and now understand the similarities/differences).

Comment: I will need to learn what to add to the interface in order to use the bindings for the observable collection. I also seem to have an issue now when I add items to the new "Menu" Items list, where an exception is thrown: "This type of CollectionView does not support changes to its SourceCollection from a thread different from the Dispatcher thread." I will troubleshoot.